# Setting an UICollectionViewDataSource on a UITableViewCell Crashes App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement a Facebook-Style Card with an Image Gallery, but whenever I want to set the ***DataSource*** of the *UICollectionView* the App Crashes with a BAD_ACCS Exception.

Whenever a Post has Images, I instantiante an Object, Called

```
MyCustomDataSource
```

(which adopts the UICollectionViewDataSource protocol), the App then Crashes giving an BAD_ACCESS Exception, I don't really know what is happening. XCode6 it's not complaining on the Implemented methods of the DataSource, (I'm implementing all the Required Methods) and this Still Happens.

Why is this happening??

Comment: Are you creating a strong property or ivar for MyCustomDataSource so it doesn't get deallocated?

Comment: your data source should be a viewcontroller, not a uitableviewcell. not sure if you're getting these objects mixed up or not. But you want to have one viewcontroller, which contains the collectionView, to be a datasource and delegate of that collectionview. this view controller will generate many posts and images for the cells and whatever you want to display in the collectionview. right now it's hard to tell what you're doing, so you can post some code to help.

Comment: The DataSource is not the TableViewCell, Whenever a Cell that has the UICollectionView it's presented, I allocate a MyCustomDataSource object and set it to the Cell's CollectionView.